# Issues in Validation

Tags: java, android

When i am click on Submit button Validation is not processed is there any mistake?if edit text is empty it will goes to next activity validation is not processed  ?Can any one solve this

```
public void submitDetails(View v)
{
    et  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first);
    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.last);
    et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
    et4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateofbirth);
    et5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Address);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    String first = et.getText().toString();
    String last = et1.getText().toString();
    String email = et2.getText().toString();
    String mobile = et3.getText().toString();
    String birth = et4.getText().toString();
    String address = et5.getText().toString();
    String emailpatern =  "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

    if (et.equals(""))
        et.setError("pls enter name");
    else if (et2.equals("")&&!et2.equals(emailpatern))
        et2.setError("Pls Enter Valid Email");
    else if(et3.equals(""))
         et3.setError("Enter Mobile Number");
    else if (et4.equals(""))
         et4.setError("Enter Date of Birth");
    else if (et5.equals(""))
         et5.setError("fil the fileds");
    else
        {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Result.class);
                i.putExtra("k1",first);
                i.putExtra("k2",last);
                i.putExtra("k3",email);
                i.putExtra("k4",mobile);
                i.putExtra("k5",birth);
                i.putExtra("k6",address);
                startActivity(i);
        }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are comparing the EditText object itself instead of the text. You have plenty of variables that are getting the text, why not use those? For example, instead of `if (et.equals`, use `if(first.equals`?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the references of the EditText are equals to an empty string `""` and this will never return `true`.

Replace :

```
et.equals("")
```

By

```
et.getText().trim().equals("")
```

You must do the same for all your EditText and you can use the variables you have with the content of the EditText..

You code should looks like :

```
if (first.trim().equals(""))
    et.setError("pls enter name");
else if (last.trim().equals("")&&!email.trim().equals(emailpatern))
    // ...
else{
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Result.class);
    i.putExtra("k1",first);
    i.putExtra("k2",last);
    i.putExtra("k3",email);
    i.putExtra("k4",mobile);
    i.putExtra("k5",birth);
    i.putExtra("k6",address);
    startActivity(i);
}
```